# A fix for my Python While Loop not executing my last line

Tags: python-3.x

The code I wrote will not execute the last calculation within the program.

```
height = float(input("Enter the height from which the ball is dropped: "))

index = float(input("Enter the bounciness index of the ball: "))

bounces = float(input("Enter the number of times the ball bounces: "))

distance = 0

while bounces > 0:

    distance = height*index

    x = distance*index

    y = x*index

    td = distance + x + y

    totald = td*bounces

    bounces -= 1

print()

print("Total distance traveled is %.3f" % totald)
```

I expected the output for the calculation of: bounces(distance + x + y)= total

ex. 3(12.5 + 6.25 + 3.125)= 65.625

But it only print out the calculation of: distance + x + y = total

ex. 12.5 + 6.25 + 3.125 = 21.875‬

Comment: Where are you expecting the total to be multiplied by 3?

Comment: For this test, Yes. But overall No. I was trying to create a program for any number entered to be calculated. But ran into this issue first and couldn't get pass it and couldn't move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You face this problem because that in any iteration `bounces` is decremented and `totald` is set to `bounce*td`. So, the final value of 'totald' is determined in the last iteration, wherein `bounce` is `1`. To prevent this problem, you can add value of `td*bounce`to `totald` at each iteration.

try this:

```
distance = 0
totald = 0

while bounces > 0:

    distance = height*index

    x = distance*index

    y = x*index

    td = distance + x + y

    totald += td

    bounces -= 1

print()

print("Total distance traveled is %.3f" % totald)
```

or simply:

```
distance = 0
totald = 0

if bounces > 0:

    distance = height*index

    x = distance*index

    y = x*index

    td = distance + x + y

    totald = td*bounces

print()

print("Total distance traveled is %.3f" % totald)
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Dumping code isn't super useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you provide the line I need to change to make the code with the abilities to execute beyond just multiples of 3?